# Submit a form of another website

Tags: php, curl

I want, from my website, execute the form of another website and read result, trying to use Curl but im not sure if its the good way.

The website i want to execute the form is http://www.rpe.rbq.gouv.qc.ca/GIC_Public_NET/RPE/GIC111/GIC111PR01RechercheEntrepreneur.aspx

the form redirect to itself but when i send the form myself using a browser the url is GIC111PR02ListeResultats.aspx

does what im trying to do is possible ?

```
extract($_POST);

//set POST variables
$url = 'http://www.rpe.rbq.gouv.qc.ca/GIC_Public_NET/RPE/GIC111/GIC111PR01RechercheEntrepreneur.aspx';
$fields = array(
                        'ctl00$ZonePrincipal$txtNom'=>urlencode('jean-sebastien duhamel')
                );
$fields_string ='';
//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: The page uses Javascript. CURL doesn't execute the scripts.

Comment: Does there is a way to do what im trying to do ?

Comment: What is that you are trying to achieve? And why would you try to post a form on another website? You could just create your own form and post to the same URL as the form you are trying to imitate.

Comment: I want to create a directories, people who want to registe to my directories need a RBQ licence. And to verifie the RBQ licence i need to go at the website in my original post.